# How to run the Docker image to see the changes made on script?

Tags: python, docker

Dockerfile is look like this:

```
FROM python:3

ADD my_script.py /

RUN pip install pystrich

CMD [ "python", "./my_script.py" ]
```

This runs smoothly, whatever the output is from `my_script.py`, docker run command gives that output.

Once I made changes on `my_script.py`, do I need to re-run the `docker build` command and run that image again to see the changes from output?

Comment: Mount your code as a volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to rebuild the image because you add it to the image at build time.

You can avoid the re-build if you map the file as a volume when you run the container.

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install pystrich

CMD [ "python", "/my_script.py" ]
```

```
docker run -v my_script.py:/my_script.py ...
```